# Coercing multiple time-series columns to factors in large dataframe

Tags: r, time-series, large-data, coerce

I would like to know if there is an "easy/quick" way to convert character variables to factor.

I am aware, that one could make a vector with the column names and then use `lapply`. However, I am working with a large data frame with more than 200 variables, so it would be preferable not having to write the 200+ names in the vector.

I am also aware that I can coerce the entire data frame by using `lapply`, `type.convert` and `sapply`, but as I am working with time series data where some is categorical, and some is numerical, I am not interested in that either.

Is there any way to use the column number in this? I.e. `[ ,2:200]`? I tried the following, but without any luck:

```
df[ ,2:30] <- lapply(df[ ,2:30], type.convert)
sapply(df, factor)
```

With the solution above, I would still have to do multiple of them, but it would still be quicker than writing all the variable names.

I also have a feeling a loop might be usable here, but I would not be sure of how to write it out, or if it is even a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you write, that you need to convert (all?) character variables to factors, you could use `mutate_if` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mutate_if(df, is.character, as.factor)
```

With this you only operate on columns for which `is.character` returns `TRUE`, so you don't need to worry about the column positions or names.

Comment: I think you're better off using `mutate_at` so you can specify the individual columns.  An arbitrary example using the `mtcars` data would be `mutate_at(mtcars, vars(mpg:wt), funs(as.factor))`

Comment: @DaveGruenewald Not sure if the `*_at` would be quicker, as OP writes *With the solution above, I would still have to do multiple of them, but it would still be quicker than writing all the variable names.* Here, the `*_if` should work best IMO.

Comment: Fair point, but it also isn't clear that he was *all* character columns as factors either.  Suppose it ultimately depends on OP's data structure

Answer (score 2):

```
df[ ,2:30] <- lapply(df[ ,2:30], as.factor)
```